# How to search children/descendants by regular expression title in pywinauto?

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto, microsoft-ui-automation

I am trying to get children/descendant UI elements of another UI element by a regexp title.

For example, the following code should work.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application, WindowSpecification
root_ws: WindowSpecification = (
    Application(backend="uia")
        .connect(path="C:/program.exe")
        .window(title_re="^Program *")
)
root_ws.descendants(title_re="^abc*", control_type="DataItem")
```

However, as described (by [Vasily Ryabov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3648361/vasily-ryabov)) [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432544/pywinauto-how-do-i-get-the-list-of-returned-elements#comment86088573_49458557), `title_re is not possible for children/descendants`.

The function that supports search of children by a regular expression is `find_elements`, however it doesn't accept `root_ws` as parent:

```
import pywinauto
pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements(title_re="^abc*", 
                                    top_level_only=False,
                                    parent=root_ws)
```

throws an exception `AttributeError: 'StaticWrapper' object has no attribute 'rich_text'`

How could I find a child of another UI element by only having a regexp title?

Comment: Can you provide full traceback of the exception? Also the code is not equivalent, because you missed param `backend="uia"` for `find_elements`. It is passed by higher level object to `find_elements` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pywinauto 0.6.8, you can simply use `child_window` to find an element. It takes the same exact parameters as `find_elements`.

Example:

```py
from pywinauto.application import Application

root_ws = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="C:/program.exe").window(title_re="^Program *")
root_ws.child_window(title_re="^abc*", control_type="DataItem")
```